# Pass '%09' as a string command line arg in Visual Studio Python

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, tabs

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Debugger in the Python tools plugin (which is FABULOUS by the way).

When I set my command line args to `BON7%09/13`, I want that passed in as one argument.
But, Visual Studio tells me that I have two command line args: `BON7` and `/13`, not one.

This is because **%09** is ASCII code for tab, and Visual Studio it converting it to the tab char.

But I don't want it converted. How do I block that conversion?
I've tried all the usual escapes:

- Single quotes around the string,
- Double quotes around the string,
- Backslash in front of the %,
  but none of those help.

How do I make Visual Studio treat that command line arg as pure text?

For what it's worth, it doesn't convert the %09 when I run it from the command line without Visual Studio. Also, I tried the same thing in C#, and it works fine there.

Comment: No repro in either a C# or a C++ console mode app.  Don't keep the project type and the VS version a secret.

Comment: Good point, I assumed it was VS behavior across all projects, but it actually seems unique to the microsoft Python Tools plugin. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a work around of using `%3709` which if consumed as you described should create `%09`.

Comment: Great idea! Doesn't seem to work, though. VS eats the "%3" and leaves the "7". Looks like a bug/feature in the VS python tools, I think. Appears they're explictly looking for the tab character ascii code but not any other code.